# Can Python generators be invoked non-lazily?

Tags: python, generator

I know that in Python, generators are invoked lazily. For example:

```
>>> def G():
...     print('this was evaluated now 1')
...     yield 1
...     print('this was evaluated now 2')
...     yield 2
...
>>> g = G()
>>> next(g)
this was evaluated now 1
1
>>> next(g)
this was evaluated now 2
2
```

The line `print('this was evaluated now 1')` was evaluated only after the first `next(g)` was called.

I wonder whether there is a simple way to invoke the generator non-lazily. This means that when calling `g = G()`, the function would calculate everything up to and including the first `yield` result, without actually yielding. Then, on the first call to `next(g)`, the already-calculated result will be yielded, and also everything up to and including the second `yield` result would be calculated. And so on.

How can this be achieved?

---

Here is the expected behavior under this non-lazy scheme:

```
>>> g = G()
this was evaluated now 1
>>> next(g)
1
this was evaluated now 2
>>> next(g)
2
```

---

Here is a solution attempt, which does not work:

```
>>> class NonLazyGenerator():
...     def __init__(self,G):
...         self.g = G()
...         self.next_value = next(self.g)
...
...     def __next__(self):
...         current_value = self.next_value
...         try:
...             self.next_value = next(self.g)
...         except StopIteration:
...             pass
...         return current_value
...
>>> g = NonLazyGenerator(G)
this was evaluated now 1
>>> next(g)
this was evaluated now 2
1
>>> next(g)
2
```

This fails since the value is yielded only after the `return` statement, while the calculation of everything up to the next `yield` happens before the `return` statement. This example made me realize that it may not be possible to perform what I am seeking for, since it would require doing steps after the function has returned (might require multi-threading).

Comment: Why would you want that? Yielding would still do calculation work for the next result, so you are not gaining anything.

Comment: I can give an explanation for why I would want this, but the purpose of my question is not to find justifications for or against doing this, but rather to understand how to do this.

Comment: The reason is that I have a function which has in its body the a `yield` statement, and this turns the function into a generator. However, this `yield` is only reachable conditioned on the value of an argument to the function. I want the function to behave as a regular function when this argument is `False`, and as a generator otherwise. If generators would be evaluated non-lazily. this would solve the problem.
(Of course, there are other ways to solve this problem, and of course, this isn't necessary good programming, but as I said, I'm currently only interested in an answer to the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably write some kind of decorator for it, such as:

```
def eagergenerator(mygen):
    class GeneratorWrapper:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.g = mygen(*args, **kwargs)
            self.last = next(self.g)
        def __iter__(self):
            return self
        def __next__(self):
            if self.last is self:
                raise StopIteration
            fake_yield = self.last
            try:
                self.last = next(self.g)
                return fake_yield
            except StopIteration:
                self.last = self
                return fake_yield
    return GeneratorWrapper
```

Then you can simply decorate your normal generators:

```
@eagergenerator
def G():
    print("one")
    yield 1
    print("two")
    yield 2
```

which will work as follows:

```
>>> g = G()                               
one                                       
>>> next(g)                               
two                                       
1                                         
>>> next(g)                               
2                                         
>>> next(g)                               
Traceback (most recent call last):        
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>     
  File "eagergen.py", line 10, in __next__
    raise StopIteration                   
StopIteration                             
>>>
```

Comment: A nice example (+1). I'd like to add few notes if somebody wants to base own code on it. I did not try, but I think an "empty" generator needs to be handled as a special case with `try/next/except StopIteration` in `__init__`. Also the value of StopIteration (i.e. the generator's return value) should be preserved by the wrapper.

Comment: This was just a proof-of-concept, but feel free to edit my answer!

Answer (score 1):

credit: this was inspired by @L3viathan answer

In this version, [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) is used to store the one yielded value the wrapper is behind the original generator.

```
import itertools

def eagergenerator(mygen):
    class GeneratorWrapper:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.g0, self.g1 = itertools.tee(mygen(*args, **kwargs))
            self._next0()
        def _next0(self):
            try:
                next(self.g0)
            except StopIteration:
                pass
        def __iter__(self):
            return self
        def __next__(self):
            self._next0()
            return next(self.g1)
    return GeneratorWrapper
```